# Simple MySQL query not selecting all data?

Tags: mysql

I know a bit about MySQL, but not enough to know why this query is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader LIKE 'value';
```

I have a database of files which contains uploader names. Yet, when I search for an uploader name it misses a lot of the entries, even though the name is completely identical all through.

No idea why it does this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sonny, you need some wildcards in [that there `LIKE` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader LIKE '%value%';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use like you usually want to include some sort of wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader LIKE '%value%';
```

For undefined number of characters use `%` for just one additional character use `_`.

Some examples:

`'%value%'` will match:

```
somevaluesome
somevalue
valuesome
value
```

Another sample:
`'_value_'` will match:

avaluea

but not

```
value
avalue
valuea
```

You can find more wildcards here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for an identical uploader name, for example, an uploader named Jason, then use the equals comparison operator.

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader = 'Jason';
```

If you would like to match ssJasonsss, Jason, etc, then use:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader LIKE '%Jason%';
```

Comment: I tried first using = but the result was the same. Solved using above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE uploader LIKE '%value%'
```

read more details about [Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)